# SharePoint site issues on iPad and mobile devices

Tags: 2010, navigation, apple-ios

I have SharePoint 2010 site that was working fine on mobile devices and iPad. I made some changes, like adding some site pages and changing the ordering of pages. Since then the pages in navigation that have a further slide over menu are not opening in iPad and some android devices.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions on the [following](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tehnoonr/archive/2014/10/27/safari-7-1-on-mac-computers-causes-multiple-issues-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx) link and I was able to solve the issue.